# Installed eth-cli on command line ubuntu 20.4, but command not found?

Tags: error, ubuntu, command-line, cli, eth-cli

Sorry but a bit new to this. I used the command to install eth-cli:

**npm install -g eth-cli**

But I get all these deprecated errors and the command "eth-cli" shows command not found. How do I verify it even installed properly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is not eth-cli. It's just **eth**