# Get Private key from UUID of old eth Wallet

Tags: private-key, eth-cli

I have a UUID generated by the eth-cli (2016).
Is it possible to generate the private key from this UUID, or does the UUID get generated from the private key?

If it works from UUID to private key, how do i do it?
I already tried to download the original eth-cli wallet, but I couldn't find anything usefull about it (i only found geth and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123625/installed-eth-cli-on-command-line-ubuntu-20-4-but-command-not-found), which ended in "Package no longer supported").

Comment: Uuid are 128 bits, on the other hand Ethereum's private keys are 256 bits. So it seems unlikely you can recover a private key given a UUID. You could try asking in their github repo https://github.com/protofire/eth-cli/issues.

Comment: @Ismael That is not the client i was using. This client was released in 2017. I think the one i was using isn't maintained anymore and i can't seem to find it. You don't happen to know what might have happend with the initial one?

Comment: Some of the common wallets in that time were geth, and ethereum wallet. Both use a json file to store the private key encrypted.